# unique element/s for array in every row

Tags: c, arrays

I have a question on how to show unique elements in an array. The program consists of two nested loops. The first counter is for rows and the other is for the letters, and the second counter outputs the letters in the array in the order.

The issue I am having, is that after the first and second row some elements start to repeat themselves(C primer plus 6th edition 241pg num 4)

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(void){

    char lets[29] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";


    for(int i =0; i<6; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<=i; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", lets[j+i]);
        }


        printf("\n");
    }
    }
```

My Output

```
A
BC
CDE
DEFG
EFGHI
FGHIJK
```

Required Output

```
A
BC
DEF
GHIJ
KLMNO
PQRSTU
```

Comment: Don't post images of text. Not clear what you mean. There is a 1D array, there are only columns/entries in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra offset or you never reach the end of the alphabet:

```
char lets[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; // no need to give array size, automatic size is OK

int start = 0;

for(int i =0; i<6; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<=i; j++)
    {
        printf("%c", lets[j+i+start]);
    }
    start += i;  # shift letters

    printf("\n");
}
```

result:

```
A
BC
DEF
GHIJ
KLMNO
PQRSTU
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

char lets[29] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

int k=0;
for(int i =0; i<6; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<=i; j++)
    {
        printf("%c", lets[k]);
        k++;
    }


    printf("\n");
}
}
```

Output:

```
A
BC
DEF
GHIJ
KLMNO
PQRSTU
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters you declared the array `lets` as having 29 elements though initialized it explicitly only with 27 elements including the terminating zero.

```
char lets[29] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
         ^^^
```

Secondly it is not clear why are you using this magic number `6`

```
for(int i =0; i<6; i++)
              ^^^
```

If you will take another alphabet your code will be invalid.

Take into account that you should check whether the current outputted symbol is outside the terminating zero.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char lets[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    for ( size_t i = 0, j = 0; lets[j]; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t k = i + 1; lets[j] && k; --k ) putchar( lets[j++] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
A
BC
DEF
GHIJ
KLMNO
PQRSTU
VWXYZ
```

Its work does not depend on the size of the character array. It can work with any alphabet.

Consider for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char lets[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for ( size_t i = 0, j = 0; lets[j]; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t k = i + 1; lets[j] && k; --k ) putchar( lets[j++] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this case the output will look like

```
A
BC
DEF
GHIJ
KLMNO
PQRSTU
VWXYZab
cdefghij
klmnopqrs
tuvwxyz
```